# login Controller using PFLogInViewController in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was about to create login/signup  view controller for my application. I found `PFLogInViewController` from [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views) which looks like it make my life easier. Because it comes with ability to login from facebook and twitter.

Is it a good idea to use this library ? 
Have anyone used it before ?
Do I need a Parse.com account to use this ?

In my previous app I implemented the login view on my own it works good (I don't have ability to login using facebook). But this library claims that it can be done just by importing it.

Comment: I have no experience with this library, but just looking at the Readme on GitHub, you need to have a Parse.com application key which I assume requires a Parse account.

Comment: @AlexBlundell Can I use my own back end server for managing registrations ? Or do I have to use something that comes from parse ?

Comment: You have to use the Parse.com servers